# Rxjs - emit if the pair appears

Tags: rxjs

Question about rxjs puzzle.

I have a random numbers stream. 
the number takes [0-9] numbers. so the stream looks like:

`0, 4, 2, 8, 9, 0, 3, 9, ...`

I want to emit `true` if number 9 after 5. In other words, if the pair [5, 9] appears in the stream.

what the pipe should be?

Example code is here:

```
import { interval } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

const numbers = 
  interval(500).pipe(map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))); // it takes [0-9] numbers

numbers.pipe(
  // what the pipe should be?
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `pairwise()` operator:

```js
src$.pipe(
 pairwise(),
 map(([prev, crt]) => prev === 5 && crt === 9)
)
```

Comment: amazing. I posted the question and you answered in 5 mins. what a man.